# Match text against wildcard expressions in database?

Tags: mysql, database, wildcard

Given an input string, I'd like to return the rows from a (MySQL) database that contain a wildcard expression that would match the string. For example, if I have a table containing these wildcard expressions:

```
foo.*
foo.bar.*
erg.foo.*
```

and my input string is "foo.bar.baz", then I should get the rows "foo.*" and "foo.bar.*".

Any ideas on how this can be implemented? I'm hoping it can be accomplished with a query, but I might have to select all relevant rows and do the matching in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   'foo.bar.baz' RLIKE match
```

You are not limited to the wildcards and can use any regular expression `MySQL` supports.

However, if you only want to process asterisk wildcards, you may use this syntax:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   'foo.bar.baz' LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('\\', '\\\\'), '.', '\\.'), '%', '\\%'), '*', '%') ESCAPE '\\'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I think I had my mind made up that it was going to be complicated, so I didn't see the obvious.